# How to notify React Native that the size of a custom view has changed?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm writing a custom view for React Native iOS.

Basically I have to make the text as large as possible (based on the view of the current view). I've done it by overriding `reactSetFrame` and changing the frame. The only issue is that the position of the view is wrong, here's a screenshot:

[image: overlapping views]

It seems that the "layout manager" of react native thinks that the views have height 0.

Here the code:

```
- (void)reactSetFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  [super reactSetFrame:frame];

  NSLog(@"react set frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));

  [self fitText:self.text];
}

- (void)fitText:(NSString *)text {
    // ... get the correct font size and expected size    
    [self setFont:font];

    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;

    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;

    NSLog(@"new frame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));

    self.frame = newFrame;
}
```

basically when the frame changes I'm updating the frame with the correct dimensions based on the text that was passed.

The logs output is this:

```
2017-06-25 16:43:16.434 ABC[44836:6551225] react set frame {{0, 0}, {375, 0}}
2017-06-25 16:43:16.435 ABC[44836:6551225] new frame is {{0, 0}, {375, 69.197000000000017}}
2017-06-25 16:43:16.435 ABC[44836:6551225] react set frame {{0, 0}, {375, 0}}
2017-06-25 16:43:16.436 ABC[44836:6551225] new frame is {{0, 0}, {375, 85.996999999999986}}
```

I've tried calling `reactSetFrame` with the new frame again but it is not working. Is there a way to tell React Native that the size of a view has changed?

Comment: you want to send data from native to javascript?

Comment: @codesingh not really, I need to let the "layout manager" know the actual size of the view somehow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found a way to do this; basically react native utilise a shadow view to get the layout information. So I had to add this code to my manager

```c
- (RCTShadowView *)shadowView
{
  return [FitTextShadowView new];
}
```

which is basically telling what's the shadow view for my component.

Then I had to change the implementation of the measure function that is used by Yoga to get the correct height:

```c
@implementation FitTextShadowView

static YGSize RCTMeasure(YGNodeRef node, float width, YGMeasureMode widthMode, float height, YGMeasureMode heightMode)
{
  FitTextShadowView *shadowText = (__bridge FitTextShadowView *)YGNodeGetContext(node);
  YGSize result;

  result.width = width;
  result.height = [shadowText getHeight:shadowText.text thatFits:width];
  return result;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    YGNodeSetMeasureFunc(self.yogaNode, RCTMeasure);
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: How did you associate `text` with your custom shadow view?

Comment: @Tres check this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#properties